# Which datastructure is the best to have multiple types in the Map output value in hadoop?

Tags: java, data-structures, hadoop, vector, shuffle

I have written a map reduce programm that my value format is:

```
Integer@BitSet
```

I want to reduce the shuffle size. Is it good to use

```
Vector<Object> vec=new Vector();
vec.add(Integer);
vec.add(BitSet);
```

Is this vector large?Which datastructure is the best in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Both `BitSet` and `Integers` extend from `Object`.

So your example will work.

The `Vector` is synchronized therefore it leads performance degradation.

I would use `ArrayList` interface.

```
List<Object> bb = new ArrayList<Object>();
bb.add(new Integer(3));
bb.add(new BitSet(5));
```

I don't see any common denominator but Object only.

Other way to use single class as Structure,

```
public class Struct{
   private Integer mInt;
   private BitSet mBitSet;
}

...
Struct struct;
List<Struct> bb = new ArrayList<Struct>();
struct = new Struct(new Integer(3));
bb.add(struct);
struct = new Struct(new BitSet(5));
bb.add(struct);

....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the shuffle size, a good way to minimize it is to implement a custom Writable class. There can sometimes be a fair amount of overhead in how hadoop handles serialization of strange types, so a custom Writable gives you full control, and you can also utilize the "primitive" Writable types, which are very efficient. You could do something like this:

```
public class IntAndBitSetWritable implements Writable {

    private IntWritable n;
    private BytesWritable bytes;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        n.readFields(in);
        bytes.readFields(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        n.write(out);
        bytes.write(out);
    }

    public BitSet getBitSet() {
        return BitSet.valueOf(bytes.getBytes());
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return n.get();
    }

    public void setBitSet(BitSet b) {
        byte[] arr = b.toByteArray();
        bytes.setSize(arr.length);
        bytes.set(arr, 0, arr.length);
    }

    public void setInt(int i) {
        n.set(i);
    }

}
```

Note that the above assumes the use of Java 7, for the conversion of `BitSet` to/from `byte[]`. You may need to implement a different method of conversion if using Java 6.